# Struts2 : How to use an attribute of an action class in another action class?

Tags: struts2, attributes, action, session-variables

I have 2 Action classes : **LoadingFormAction.java** and **FormValidationAction.java**. In the first one, I create the functions which help in uploading data from an Excel file, and in the second I need to validate the loaded data according to the other fields values. LoadingFormAction.java control the view Form.jsp and FormValidationAction.java the view FormValidation.jsp. My question is : **How to evaluate the attributes of the first action and use them in the second Action??** Is it obligatory to pass it as a **session parameter**? Thank you a lot.

Comment: yup can pass a request param to second action

Comment: can you share with me a simple code for it? thank you

Comment: Not to say you don't have reasons, but why not just validate the data in the same action with a different method? Is the validation action used anywhere else than after the file upload? If not, make things simple and just write a validation method in your upload action, then perform a redirect based on your validation result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<action name="LoadingFormActionName" class="com.test.LoadingFormAction">
    <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">FormValidationActionName</param>
        <param name="yourProperty">${yourProperty}</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

Where `yourProperty` is the parameter of your `LoadingFormAction` class which you want to pass
to `FormValidationAction` class. You need to declare getter/setter for this variable in both the classes. Also, `LoadingFormActionName`and `FormValidationActionName` are the corresponding action names.